# My <audio> element will not play in Safari 6.1 on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, html5-audio

The code is very simple, and it works perfectly fine on all browsers on Maveric, iOS, Android, but somehow it does not play in Safari 6.1 on Mountain Lion. Is there something I am missing in order to make it play?

In my html:

```
<audio controls id="answer1">
   <source src="audio/answer1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
   <source src="audio/answer1.wav" type="audio/wav">
   <source src="audio/answer.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

In my .js:

```
var answer1 = document.getElementById('answer1');

jQuery('#game-launch-btn').click( function() {
    answer1.play();
});
```

Greatful for any tips or hints :) Have a nice day.